# Has my HTC got spy apps installed on it?

Tags: security

I have an HTC Desire 510 and have received weird text messages like "link HTC **********" and "htcpairerrorreboot 25:%. \" and then a heap of random signals. I also have to keep adjusting the brightness as it keeps going to the lowest setting. Do u have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Your device may have a virus/malware on it that is corrupting your phone. I recommend using [Avast Antivirus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avast.android.mobilesecurity&hl=en) or some other virus remover app that checks the contents of your phone and wipes away the pesky little buggards.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible that your device might have a spy app installed.

Unfortunately, it's really hard to find the malware app (if it's really there) as these apps can hide from the menu and from app settings too. Uninstall any suspicious app you don't recognize.

If your device is rooted, try checking for root access logs in your root manager and see if any unwanted app has root access. Also, check for device administrators (settings->security->device administrators) to see if there's any unwanted app has become the admin.

If none of the above options shows anything. Your final option is reflashing the stock ROM. Formatting will not help as the malware apps gain higher level permissions and stay hidden in the phone to be activated again.

Reflashing the stock ROM again will ensure that there's nothing left.